# how to make slider control jump directly in windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider

Consider this,
In Windows Phone, I have a slider control, Minimum=1, Maximum=10, SmallChange=1

Lets say the value=5

Now, if I tap on the right end of slider, the thumb moves by a value 1. Similarly, clicking on slider to the left of thumb moves the thumb by value 1 to the left.

I want the slider to directly jump to the place I tap on the slider. For example, thumb is currently at 5, and I tap somewhere near the position where the value should be 9. Instead of the thumb moving to position 6, I want it to directly jump to 9.

Thanks,
Saad.

Answer (score 0):

there is a LargeChange property. this property denotes the jumps the slider makes. use that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.95).aspx

the only way by default is to drag the slider to location.